# How do I rotate an object's parent without the child being moved along?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game on unity 2d I have spaceship and a planet. The planet is orbiting a star so I made a script that parents the planet to the player when I get within a range so the planet doesn't fly past or into the player. This script makes the player move with the planet so they land on it and fly around it easily.
Here is the script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParentPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject Player;

    private float Dist;
    [SerializeField] float Threshold;
    private CircleCollider2D ParentTrigger;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ParentTrigger = GetComponents<CircleCollider2D>()[1];
        ParentTrigger.isTrigger = true;
        ParentTrigger.radius = Threshold / transform.localScale.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if(collider.gameObject == Player)
        {
            collider.gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if(collider.gameObject == Player)
        {
            collider.gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, Threshold);
    }
}
```

The problem is that as the planet rotates it ends up moving the player that has been parented to it. How can I make the planet's rotation not affect the position and rotation of the player, but still make the planets position affect the position of the player?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set the child's parent to null before the rotation, do the rotation, and then reparent the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be what you're looking for but I'm going to add it reguardless. Given that the Child-object will follow the parent, I would suggest putting the planet and spaceship as a child of the empty gameobject. Then you could rotate the the planet object, and if planets are in movement, you could add the movement to the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of parenting the player, write a script to set its position to the planets + some offset, and then the rotation wouldn't be an issue. Alternatively, if the player doesn't rotate at all, add constraints to its Rigidbody. Maybe something like this:

```
player.transform.position = planet.transform.position + offset;
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

To rotate an object's parent without the child being moved along, you can use the SetParent() method. This method allows you to set a new parent for the object, while keeping its local position, rotation and scale unchanged. You can then rotate the new parent without affecting the child.

You can use the following code to rotate an object's parent without the child being moved along in Unity3D:

```
// Get the parent transform of the object 
Transform parentTransform = transform.parent; 

// Store the current position of the child object 
Vector3 childPosition = transform.position; 

// Rotate the parent transform 
parentTransform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 45f); 

// Reset the position of the child object to its original position 
transform.position = childPosition;
```